# How can I get screenshot of a specific window in C#?

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, window, screenshot

I used the Graphics class in C# to write a code which took the screenshot of my screen. The code-

```
Bitmap bitmapScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Graphics graphicsScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapScreenshot);
graphicsScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
```

Though I can't find a way to do the same thing with any of my opened applications/windows, so is there a way to do this using the Graphics class and if not in Graphics class how can I do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to bring the target app window you wish to screenshot to the foreground like this:

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

public static void bringToFront(string title) {
    // Get a handle to the Calculator application.
    IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, title);

    // Verify that Calculator is a running process.
    if (handle == IntPtr.Zero) {
        return;
    }

    // Make Calculator the foreground application
    SetForegroundWindow(handle);
}
```

Once the window is in the foreground, you can take the screen shot so your code would look like this:

```
bringToFront("<Your target app window name>");
Bitmap bitmapScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Graphics graphicsScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapScreenshot);
graphicsScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
```